# Selenium Python: Find Next Element and/or Find Changing Element

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, findelement

Trying to find the price element of an item and return and store that attribute. The item name is clearly defined but the price varies.

Element HTML:

```
<div tabindex="0" class="item-img" style="background-image:url(&quot;//images.neopets.com/items/snowfood_chiapopblueberry.gif&quot;);" alt="Mmmm, a frozen blueberry Chia Pop.  Just what your Neopet needs to cool down." title="Mmmm, a frozen blueberry Chia Pop.  Just what your Neopet needs to cool down." border="1" onclick="confirmPurchase(this)" onkeyup="clickElement(event)" data-name="Blueberry Chia Pop" data-price="560" data-link="haggle.phtml?obj_info_id=8590&amp;stock_id=402513825&amp;g=3"></div>
```

Code I have tried:

```
time.sleep(10)
driver.get("https://www.neopets.com/objects.phtml?type=shop&obj_type=37")
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 'Blueberry Chia Pop')]")
print("Item In Stock")
item = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@data-name='Blueberry Chia Pop']")
item_price = item.find_element(By.XPATH, "following-sibling::td").get_attribute()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the HTML:

```
<div tabindex="0" class="item-img" style="background-image:url(&quot;//images.neopets.com/items/snowfood_chiapopblueberry.gif&quot;);" alt="Mmmm, a frozen blueberry Chia Pop.  Just what your Neopet needs to cool down." title="Mmmm, a frozen blueberry Chia Pop.  Just what your Neopet needs to cool down." border="1" onclick="confirmPurchase(this)" onkeyup="clickElement(event)" data-name="Blueberry Chia Pop" data-price="560" data-link="haggle.phtml?obj_info_id=8590&amp;stock_id=402513825&amp;g=3"></div>
```

Assuming the *item name* being *"Blueberry Chia Pop"* and the *item price* being *"560"* to print the price you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *css_selector*:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[data-name='Blueberry Chia Pop']").get_attribute("data-price"))
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@data-name='Blueberry Chia Pop']").get_attribute("data-price"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  ```